How to fix "MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent"
I am having trouble with Dagger Hilt in my Android application. Although I have implemented the required components, the app still throws an IllegalStateException. Below are the details of my configuration:
Viewmodel:
@HiltViewModel
class TodoListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ToDoRepository
): ViewModel() {

    val todos = repository.getToDos()

    private val _uiEvent =  Channel<UIEvent>()
    val uiEvent = _uiEvent.receiveAsFlow()

    private var deletedTodo: ToDo? = null

    fun onEvent(event: ToDoListEvent) {
        when(event) {
            is ToDoListEvent.OnToDoClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UIEvent.Navigate(Routes.ADD_EDIT_TODO + "?todoId=${event.toDo.id}"))
            }
            is ToDoListEvent.OnAddToDoClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UIEvent.Navigate(Routes.ADD_EDIT_TODO))
            }
            is ToDoListEvent.OnUndoDeleteClick -> {
                deletedTodo?.let { todo ->
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        repository.insertToDo(todo)
                    }
                }
            }
            is ToDoListEvent.OnDeleteToDoClick -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    deletedTodo = event.toDo
                    repository.deleteToDo(event.toDo)
                    sendUiEvent(UIEvent.ShowSnackBar(
                        message = "Todo deleted",
                        action = "Undo"
                    ))
                }
            }
            is ToDoListEvent.OnDoneChange -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    repository.insertToDo(
                        event.toDo.copy(
                            isDone = event.isDone
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendUiEvent(event: UIEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiEvent.send(event)
        }
    }
}

@HiltAndroidApp
class ToDoApp : Application()

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            ToDoListAppTheme {
                ToDoListScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}


@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ToDoListScreen(
    viewModel: TodoListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val todos = viewModel.todos.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.uiEvent.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is UIEvent.Navigate -> {}
                is UIEvent.ShowSnackBar -> {
                    val result = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        message = event.message,
                        actionLabel = event.action
                    )

                    if (result == SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed) {
                        viewModel.onEvent(ToDoListEvent.OnUndoDeleteClick)
                    }

                }
                else -> Unit
            }
        }
    }

    Scaffold (
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {viewModel.onEvent(ToDoListEvent.OnAddToDoClick)}
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_add),
                    contentDescription = "Add"
                )
            }
        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn (
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            items(todos.value) { todo ->
                ToDoItem(
                    toDo = todo,
                    onEvent = viewModel::onEvent,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .clickable {
                            viewModel.onEvent(ToDoListEvent.OnToDoClick(todo))
                        }
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

I have checked my Gradle dependencies and ensured that the necessary plugins and annotations are applied.
Moudle level build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.13"
}

android {
    namespace = "me.huynhducphu.todolistapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "me.huynhducphu.todolistapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"

    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)

    implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
    annotationProcessor(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)

    implementation (libs.hilt.android)
    annotationProcessor(libs.hilt.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)
    ksp(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

libs.version.toml:
[versions]
agp = "8.6.0-alpha03"
daggerCompiler = "2.51.1"
hiltCompiler = "1.2.0"
hiltLifecycleViewmodel = "1.0.0-alpha03"
javapoet = "1.13.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.1"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2024.04.01"
lifecycleViewmodelCompose = "2.8.2"
navigationCompose = "2.7.7"
roomRuntime = "2.6.1"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-hilt-compiler = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltCompiler" }
androidx-hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel", version.ref = "hiltLifecycleViewmodel" }
androidx-hilt-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "hiltCompiler" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-compose = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose", version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodelCompose" }
androidx-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", version.ref = "navigationCompose" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
dagger-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler", version.ref = "daggerCompiler" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "daggerCompiler" }
hilt-android-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "daggerCompiler" }
hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "daggerCompiler" }
javapoet = { module = "com.squareup:javapoet", version.ref = "javapoet" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

Despite these implementations, I am encountering the following error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: me.huynhducphu.todolistapp, PID: 19683
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class me.huynhducphu.todolistapp.MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
    at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:62)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.createInternal(HiltViewModelFactory.java:206)
    at androidx.hilt.navigation.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltNavBackStackEntry.kt:75)
    at androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.HiltViewModelKt.createHiltViewModelFactory(HiltViewModel.kt:95)
    at me.huynhducphu.todolistapp.ui.todo_list.ToDoListScreenKt.ToDoListScreen(ToDoListScreen.kt:88)
    ...


App crashed when I used hiltViewModel().

Please include all the relevant information like contents of libs.version.toml directly, like it described in this guide. It would also be great to see less irrelevant information like ViewModel or @Composable implementation details.

I don't know from where you got your gradle setup, but there are several issues here.
First, as seen in Dependency injection with Hilt you need the following gradle plugin (in app level gradle file, then applied in module level gradle file):
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51.1"

The version is the same as daggerCompiler in your version catalog. You should migrate the plugin to define it there as well, but the above will also work.
If you want to use KSP instead of kapt you should replace annotationProcessor with ksp. For Hilt that means you need this:
ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)

The following is wrong and should be removed:
ksp(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)

Also, to prevent DefaultActivityViewModelFactory not found you need to remove
implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)


Though this error was very tricky I had to scratch my head a lot to get it working.
I have followed all steps yet, i was not able to resolve this error.
The answer lies in gradle files and dependencies.

App level (build.gradle) -
\

In dependecies block
`// Dagger - Hilt
implementation(libs.hilt.android)
implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)
ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)`

In Plugins Block
alias(libs.plugins.google.devtools.ksp)
alias(libs.plugins.google.dagger.hilt.android)


Top Level (build.gradle)

In Plugin Block
alias(libs.plugins.google.devtools.ksp) apply false
alias(libs.plugins.google.dagger.hilt.android) apply false


libs.versions.toml

In [Plugins]
google-devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "2.1.0-1.0.29" }
google-dagger-hilt-android = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "2.51.1" }

In [libraries]
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "2.51.1" }
androidx-hilt-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "1.2.0" }
hilt-android-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "2.51.1" }

[Version]
Version Numbers can be updated here.. for post have mentioned in version.ref
Hope this helps.
